# Chaining unknown functions/methods in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

Assuming I have a jquery collection or a variable representing a jquery collection and I want to chain a jquery method to an item of the collection. For example:

```
$('#container').fadeIn();
```

So far no problem. But what if I don't know the name of the method to chain yet at the time the script is loaded because the method name is the value of an item in a configuration object?

I hope it's clear what I mean. Thank's in advance.

Comment: `$('#container')["fadeIn"]()`

Comment: it's unclear to me....

Comment: The bracket notation is the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var dynamicMethodName = "fadeIn"; // from configuration
$('#container')[dynamicMethodName]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use bracket notation:

```
$('#container')["fadeIn"]();
```

So, store the function name in a variable and then use it.

```
var funcName = "fadeIn";
$('#container')[funcName]();
```